# Python insert values for sympy.Function inside a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, sympy, derivative

Hy there,

I've defined multiple sympy matrices with time dependend angles inside.

```
import sympy as sym
R1xI = sym.Matrix([ [1,0,0],
                    [0,sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSA')(t)),-sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSA')(t))],
                    [0,sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSA')(t)),sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSA')(t))]]);

R1yI = sym.Matrix([ [sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSE')(t)),0,sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSE')(t))],
                    [0,1,0],
                    [-sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSE')(t)),0,sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSE')(t))]]);

R1zI = sym.Matrix([ [sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSR')(t)),-sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSR')(t)),0],
                    [sym.sin(sym.Function('phiSR')(t)),sym.cos(sym.Function('phiSR')(t)),0],
                    [0,0,1]]);

#       Combine the 3 rotations
R1I=np.asmatrix(np.dot(np.dot(R1xI,R1yI),R1zI));
```

I've used sympy for the reason of multiple calculation steps with this matrices, which I want to perform in an algebraic way, (Multiplications, time derivations, therefore the angles have to be time depending).

Now I'm finished with the algebraic calculations and want to insert real values for this angles.

Is there a possible way to insert them or is there a better way than using sym.Function in order to perform derivations depending on a variable?

Thank you for your advise

Comment: I've changed from sym.Function to dynamicsymbols from sympy.physics.mechanics but still not able to insert values

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stay in SymPy instead of converting to numpy: `R1I = R1xI.dot(R1yI).dot(R1zI)` and then use `R1I.subs(old, new)` where `old` is what you want to replace and `new` is the value you want it to have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but it looks like rotation matrices for me.
one way to substitute values is to use 'your_matrix.subs({symbol_name: value_to_substitue})

and insted of using np.dot, you can simply use '@' symbol between two matrices to find their product

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).